# Is it possible to port i3 to Wayland?

Tags: x11, i3, wayland

i3 runs on X11 and has a lot of functionality as a window manager. This raises the question of when or how easily it could be ported to Wayland, which has various structural advantages over X11.

Is i3 so wedded to X11 that porting it to Wayland would be more or less impossible and require a complete re-write, or is the X11-specific code in i3 contained in specific modules and the port would only require rewriting those specific modules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wayland doesn’t have the same split of components as X11, and window managers as such don’t really exist there. With Wayland, the display server and window manager are combined into one program, the compositor. In i3’s case, there is an equivalent: [Sway](https://swaywm.org/), a tiling Wayland compositor which is designed to provide the same experience as i3 on X11, including taking your existing i3 configuration.

So yes, technically it’s possible to port i3 to Wayland, and it’s already been done for you; but I suspect it’s more of a rewrite than a port (I haven’t checked).